# How can i fetch the categories in JSON url in ReactJs

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object

How can i fetch the categories in JSON url in ReactJs 
the url is 
https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/scapic-others/json/models.json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ReactJS - get json object data from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019094/reactjs-get-json-object-data-from-an-url)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ajax call libraries that you can use. But the native way, which is supported in modern browsers is using fetch API. It will give you the json and you can process it according to your need. Here is the small example. As of now , due to cross origin I cannot replicate in the editor here. But the code goes like this

```
fetch("https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/scapic-others/json/models.json")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(resultAns => { console.log(resultAns)})
```