# how to go to a specific profile after login?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

Hey I am trying to build a simple Login and Profile seeing app. Where you can Register and Login and after that it will take you to your Profile where whatever you wrote in the Registration will show. But i am stuck, I need this for my internship plase anyone help me?? Below I am posting API and front end code.

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const userRouter = require('./routes/user.route');
const loginRouter = require('./routes/login.route');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose
    .connect(uri, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
    })
    .then((res) =>
        console.log('MongoDb connected .....')
    )
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));

app.use('/users', userRouter);
app.use('/login', loginRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`App is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

user.route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user.model');

Router.route('/').get((req, res) => {
    User.find()
        .then((response) => res.json(response))
        .catch((err) =>
            res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
        );
});

Router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const {
        firstname,
        lastname,
        email,
        contact,
        password,
    } = req.body;

    const newUser = new User({
        firstname,
        lastname,
        email,
        contact,
        password,
    });

    newUser
        .save()
        .then((response) => res.json(response))
        .catch((err) =>
            res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err)
        );
});
Router.route('/:id').get((req, res) => {
    User.findById(req.params.id)
        .then((response) => res.json(response))
        .catch((err) => res.json(err));
});

module.exports = Router;
```

login.route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Router = express.Router();
const User = require('../models/user.model');

Router.route('/').post((req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
        .then((user) => {
            if (user) {
                if (req.body.password === user.password) {
                    return res.json(user);
                } else {
                    return res.json('wrong password');
                }
            } else {
                return res.json('User not found');
            }
        })
        .catch((err) => res.json('Error: ' + err));
});

module.exports = Router;
```

**Front End**
app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Route } from 'react-router';
import Login from './components/login';
import Signup from './components/signup';
import Profile from './components/profile';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Route
                        path='/'
                        exact
                        component={Login}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path='/signup'
                        exact
                        component={Signup}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path='/users/:id'
                        component={Profile}
                    />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Login extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: '',
        };
    }

    onChangeEmail = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            email: event.target.value,
        });
    };
    onChangePassword = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            password: event.target.value,
        });
    };

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const newLogin = {
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password,
        };
        axios
            .post(
                'http://localhost:5000/login',
                newLogin
            )
            .then((res) => {
                window.location =
                    '/users/' + res.data._id;
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        this.setState({
            email: '',
            password: '',
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div
                className='container'
                style={{ width: '400px' }}>
                <div style={{ marginTop: '200px' }}>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className='mb-3'>
                            <label
                                htmlFor='Email'
                                className='form-label'>
                                Email address
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.onChangeEmail}
                                type='email'
                                className='form-control'
                                id='Email'
                                aria-describedby='emailHelp'
                            />
                            <div
                                id='emailHelp'
                                className='form-text'>
                                We'll never share your email with
                                anyone else.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='mb-3'>
                            <label
                                htmlFor='Password'
                                className='form-label'>
                                Password
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.password}
                                onChange={this.onChangePassword}
                                type='password'
                                className='form-control'
                                id='Password'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            {`Dont have an account? Click `}
                            <Link to='/signup'>Here</Link>
                        </div>
                        <button
                            type='submit'
                            className='btn btn-primary'>
                            Submit
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

profile.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Profile extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            Name: '',
            LastName: '',
            email: '',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        axios
            .get('http://localhost:5000/users/')
            .then((res) => console.log(res.data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Name</h1>
                <h3>LastName</h3>
                <p>email</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What's actually not working?

Comment: I cant get the id param in login.js. But I am getting the id in the Route part in my app.js. So when i hit login button i want to console.log only the user who logged in, instead i am getting all the users. Can you tell me any way how to get the id param into login.js

Comment: To do that the best way is probably to use react context API. Im not sure that will work with the way you are doing the redirect though. You should be doing that using react router not window.location

Answer (score 0):

**res.redirect('/your_page')**

Use this when the user is saved in the database or when user is successfully authenticated

Comment: ok but then how will I put specific user data in my profile page?

Comment: You already send a json response back, use the json data in your 'profile.js' to display it. after res.json(), use res.redirect(). 
Display JSON data: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39019646/15209547