# ReactJS nested json file i can't get through the 3rd and 4rth nest

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get the data on 2nd, 3rd, and 4th nest but still can't figure it out.
I am able to fetch the first nest. which is 'msg: ok'
But when i do t: { xxx { xxx , xxx } } example image below please see.

```
t: -> sport: -> code i can't get through.
```

[nested data or multidimensional array for reactjs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKFE5.png)

**Here is the json file :** https://react.okbetscore.ph/response.json

Here is my updated code.

```
export default function MainContent() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const collectData = data.msg;

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((usefulData) => {
                console.log(usefulData);
                setLoading(false);
                setData(usefulData);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(`An error occurred: ${e}`)
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
                {!loading && <p>Fetched data</p>}

                <table>
                    {collectData}
                    {collectData.map((item, i) => (
                        <tr key={i}>
                            <td>{item.code}</td>
                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                </table>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

For jQuery.Ajax i am able to do it. But i am having difficulties with ReactJS.
Below is my code for jQuery.Ajax that i am able to pull out the nested data.

```
$.ajax({
  url:          'xxxx',
  type:         'POST',
  async:        false,
  dataType:     'json',
  crossDomain:  true,
  data:JSON.stringify({xxx}),
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: function (rep) {
    // begin accessing JSON data here
    for (var x = 0; x < rep['t']['leagueOdds'].length; x++) {
      categoryIcon  = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['league']['categoryIcon'];
      leagueID      = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['league']['id'];
      leagueName    = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['league']['name'];

      data code here successfully pull/fetch

      for (var i = 0; i < rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'].length; i++) {
        collapseID  = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['id'];
        homeIcon    = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['homeIcon'];
        homeName    = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['homeName'];
        awayIcon    = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['awayIcon'];
        awayName    = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['awayName'];
        startTime   = rep['t']['leagueOdds'][x]['matchOdds'][i]['matchInfo']['startTime'];

        var data = {"date_created":startTime};
        var date = new Date(parseInt(data.date_created));

        //Create your custom format
        var stime = (date.getMonth() + 1)+'/'+ date.getDate()  +'/'+date.getFullYear();
        var dt    = date;
        var time  = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes();

        data code here successfully pulls/fetch
        
        for (var cb = 0; cb < 36; cb++) {
          // random numbers
          c = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 2);
          d = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

          $('.home_game-results_'+collapseID).append('<div class="show score-board" id="home_projection_'+collapseID+'_'+i+'"><div class="ranBorder">'+c+' - ' +d+ '</div>');
        }
      }
    }
  },
});
```

Updated**
I was able to solve it.

```
export default function MainContent() {

    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);
    const collectData = Array(data);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch(`http://localhost:8080`)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then((usefulData) => {
                console.log(usefulData.t.sport);
                setLoading(false);
                setData(usefulData.t.sport);
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.error(`An error occurred: ${e}`)
            });
    }, []);

    return (
        <>
            <div className="App">
                {loading && <p>Loading...</p>}
                {!loading && <p>Fetched data</p>}
                <p>{data.name}</p>
                <p>{data.code}</p>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Thank you, guys, hope this help.
My reference is https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-parse-json-data-into-react-table-component/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS - get json object data from an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39019094/reactjs-get-json-object-data-from-an-url)

Comment: Thank you sir 0stone0, i am looking how to pull nested data sir.

Comment: which part of your code are you trying to get the nested data tho?

Comment: @JkAlombro this part `{collectData.map((item, i) => (` when i do collectData = data.msg; the response is OK, but when i do collectData = data.t; it doesn't show the nested tree of json from this data sample https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKFE5.png

Comment: @Krispy ow, one thing you need to remember when coding with react is that everything that affects your display SHOULD BE declared as state. Your collectData is declared as an ordinary variable and you are trying to display it. Try to declare it as state first and see what happens. If you need something to update your display, you should declare it as state.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to parse the response data using JSON.parse(), ex

```
setResponseData(JSON.parse(response.data))
```